# How to hide Excel Columns and Rows using Interop C#

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop, worksheet

I have made a simple inventory interface that will take data from access and show in datagrid view on my interface and then send the information to Excel via button click. This part works as needed but I would like to  remove the unused columns and rows after the information is sent. I am currently using VS 2015. I cant figure out what to add to accomplish this.

```
//send to excel
    private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ActiveControl = txtSerial;
        // creating Excel Application
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        // creating new WorkBook within Excel application
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

        // creating new Excelsheet in workbook
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;

        // see the excel sheet behind the program
        app.Visible = true;

        // get the reference of first sheet. By default its name is Sheet1.
        // store its reference to worksheet
        worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
        worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;

        // changing the name of active sheet
        worksheet.Name = "Inventory Search";

        // storing header part in Excel
        for (int i = 1; i < dataGridFB.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dataGridFB.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
            worksheet.Cells[1, i].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue);
            worksheet.Cells[1, i].Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
            worksheet.Cells[1, i].HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
            worksheet.Cells[1, i].Font.Size = 14;
        }

        // storing Each row and column value to excel sheet
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridFB.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridFB.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridFB.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1].HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
                worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1].Font.Size = 12;
                worksheet.Columns["A:G"].AutoFit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which particular columns do you want to delete?

Comment: Well, I will never use anything past column "E" but the rows will always be different, could be 2 "used" rows one time and "25" rows the next.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is a bit too broad, thus the answer is generic: in order to delete entire Worksheet Column you may use VBA statement like: `Columns("C").Delete, or Columns(3).EntireColumn.Delete`, or `Columns("F:K").Delete`. Similar syntax may apply to: `Rows(3).Delete`.

In order to just hide Rows/Columns use the VBA statement like shown below:

```
Rows("3:10").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Columns("C").Hidden = True
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: Unused Columns/Rows are by the definition empty, thus there is no content and nothing to delete. Do you want to hide them instead?

Comment: Yes, I want to hide them. Bad choice of words (delete)

Comment: Please refer to my extended answer.

Comment: yeah this is easy enough. Thx

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with your project. Best regards,